# Powershell - API Call - Pagination - Base64

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to query an API with PowerShell, the call uses Invoke-WebRequest and passes the results into an array ($response) in PS in JSON format.

The query only returns a set number of results so I need to pass back into the subsequent calls a base64 pagination string returned in the original result.

The string comes in the JSON response in the format:

"pagination":{"next":"H4sIAAAAAAAAAG2O2wqDMBBE/2Uei5bYVrz8ioiscUMDVm2SQkXy712FQh/6OsyZORuMHQM71BtoGlA3GxY3L+zCihrPF7v1HNaFPRLsMYVZyuC39cEjJhumOez0DzVYT/3IQ0fhPxXbmMDPLhx/Vm5BXiO2kjI5fe/IHFIHGDFRlMqkdOE8vXFPaaVykypd6aqgorgOJYQb7cPKXKaUSr4uVqxl4iQS8tHGD4B6x6ntAAAA","limit":1000,"total":9000}

if I copy and paste the base64 string into a line of code manually, it works every time, however, if I try to programmatically get the string by pulling the string out the array by using;

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://cloud.apiiuse.com/api/v3/assets/' -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Body '{"limit":1000,"next":"($Response.Content|ConvertFrom-Json).Pagination.Next"}' -UseBasicParsing
```

I get

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":"Illegal base64 character 28"}
```

Even if I try to output the string as

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://cloud.apiiuse.com/api/v3/assets/' -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Body '{"limit":1000,"next":"(($Response.Content|ConvertFrom-Json).Pagination.Next).ToString()"}' -UseBasicParsing
```

I get the same thing, which seems to indicate there's some illegal characters in the string when it's returned from the array, I'm scratching my head now as I can't think of how I can pull the string out the JSON (array) in PS in the correct format?

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `$Response.Content`? Without that, this is rather hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: $response.content is JSON output from the initial API call.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a sample value returned by `($response.content | ConvertFrom-Json).Pagination.Next`, and how you're including that value in a subsequent `Invoke-WebRequest` call.

Comment: ...yes, I gathered that. I meant what's in it *exactly*.

Comment: I'm getting correct results with this : $json = @"
{"pagination":{"next":"H4sIAAAAAAAAAG2O2wqDMBBE/2Uei5bYVrz8ioiscUMDVm2SQkXy712FQh/6OsyZORuMHQM71BtoGlA3GxY3L+zCihrPF7v1HNaFPRLsMYVZyuC39cEjJhumOez0DzVYT/3IQ0fhPxXbmMDPLhx/Vm5BXiO2kjI5fe/IHFIHGDFRlMqkdOE8vXFPaaVykypd6aqgorgOJYQb7cPKXKaUSr4uVqxl4iQS8tHGD4B6x6ntAAAA","limit":1000,"total":9000}}
"@
$response = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$next = $response.pagination.next

Comment: `-Body '{"limit":1000,"next":"($Response.Content|ConvertFrom-Json).Pagination.Next"}'` would be the problem. Single quoted strings do not interpolate, and interpolating an expression in a string (rather than a single variable) requires `$()`. The API complains about the `(` (hex codepoint 28) because that's literally getting posted. I recommend not using this complicated construction and using `Invoke-RestMethod` instead, because it natively understands JSON, and you can process and post PowerShell objects that way (`@{limit = 1000; next = $Response.Pagination.Next}`).

Comment: jdweng's method results in the same as my own attempts as the output from the API is in JSON format already so I just need to pull the pagination next string, however I think due to way, as Jeroen points out the single quoted string posts exact it's posting the wrong string. The issue with jeroen's Invoke-RestMethod is I get Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"Invalid query"} back if I use this as I don't believe the API can parse the inputs in that format although I agree it is a nice method of making the call to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I think both the answers from @jdweng and @Jeroen Mostert got me to the right place.

I now use `Invoke-RestMethod` to pull the data as pointed out it's a better method of pulling JSON etc.

So the initial data pull is now.

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://cloud.myapi.com/api/v3/assets/search' -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Body '{"limit":1000}'
```

And then create the pagination body by building the body as

```
    $Body = @"
{
    "limit`":1000,
    "next":"$($Response.Pagination.Next)"
}
"@
```

This works perfectly for the subsequent data as

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://cloud.myapi.com/api/v3/assets/search' -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $Body
```

Thanks for the input, it was very much appreciated.